# Multiple client server requests using SSL

Tags: android, ssl, android-ksoap2, sslsocketfactory

I have a piece of code which reads the server certificate and make SSLSocket connection to the server.
Following is the code at a high level:

```
// Create logon request XML in SOAP
SoapObject logonRq = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "LogonRq");
signonRQ.addProperty("UserName", username);
signonRQ.addProperty("Password", passwd);


try {
        HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(Constants.Host, Constants.Port, "", 500000);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(logonRq);
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        transport.debug = true;

        HttpsServiceConnectionSE sc = (HttpsServiceConnectionSE) transport.getServiceConnection();
        sc.setSSLSocketFactory(GetsslContext.getSSLSocketFactory());
        transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now my requirement is to receive server response and send another client request. For that, do I again need to execute the following?

```
HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(Constants.Host, Constants.Port, "", 500000);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(logonRq);
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        transport.debug = true;

        HttpsServiceConnectionSE sc = (HttpsServiceConnectionSE) transport.getServiceConnection();
        sc.setSSLSocketFactory(GetsslContext.getSSLSocketFactory());

transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Or can I simply call the below statement?

```
transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Basically, how can I make my code efficient and ensure I am not making socket/HTTPS calls unnecessarily?

Comment: why dont you create keystore file and use that to verify ur server instead, that approch is simple

Comment: @Diva Can you please elaborate more with example? Our server is one who holds username and password.

Comment: yup i wanted to say that is this the only way you wanna work or id it fine with u see other way to trust ur server certificates? as per my thinking the https request to ur server ur trying to hit

Comment: we have already read our server certificates and then only established the SSL socket. The code is working and we are able to get Success Login response from the server. The point is, what all pieces of code do I need to execute again to make another call? I don't wan to keep opening new SSL connection everytime...

Comment: then write above code as common set of api , u need to write the connecttion again and again

Comment: Ok, so you mean to say even make the connection again? Or just call transport.call every time I want to send request to the server?

Comment: create a method whick would be global static method, hence only call `transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

Comment: I just tried to make transport.call twice in the same method to check if I can re-send request w/o having to establish new connection, I get the error
Cannot set request property after connection is made

    HttpsServiceConnectionSE sc = (HttpsServiceConnectionSE) transport.getServiceConnection();
            sc.setSSLSocketFactory(GetsslContext.getSSLSocketFactory());
            transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

Comment: if u r in same activity then u can use same instance of HttpsServiceConnectionSE

Comment: @Diva I made transport.call request twice in same instance of HttpsServiceConnectionSE.

Comment: thats what , if u r in same activity dont create request also 2 times use same variable , keep it as class variable

Comment: @Diva I am not making request two times, I just called transport.call twice with in same instance in same request.

Comment: lets discuss in chat

Comment: @Diva Please send chat invite, I do not have enough points to start a chat.

Comment: Or Please up vote my question so that I can start a chat.